# Android Test Orchestrator and custom Application class

Tags: android, testing

I gave a try to *Android Test Orchestrator* and it doesn't see any tests if *Application* class were changed. Pretty easy to reproduce.

1. In Android Studio 3 preview Beta 6 create simple project with wizard
2. Create custom runner like:

```
    class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
      override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?,   context: Context?): Application {
       return super.newApplication(cl, TestApplicationClass::class.simpleName, context)
      }
    }
```

3. Replace instrumentation runner with new one
4. No test found after running instrumented tests

Any ideas? Looks like the Orchestrator depends on application class name from manifest.

I use this configuration to use special Dagger dependencies for tests.

Comment: Try to override onOrchestratorConnected() method of AJUR and put Logs to see if orchestrator is being connected for each test or not

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, with a custom test runner. Make sure that your `TestApplicationClass` does not crash at runtime. If the custom runner crashes then orchestrator will not be able to get information about the tests and will return the message:

`No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).`

That is what happened to me in my custom runner.

Good luck!